# How to publish a web application project with third party DLL (zkemkeeper.dll) that causes an error?

Tags: dll, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017

I have .net core web application project which using a third party DLL (zkemkeeper.dll a C++ DLL). Adding this library to my VS project is fine.

[image]

I can add it as a reference and everything works fine when I tried to run it. However, VS didn't recognize the library of this DLL as you can see on the below image.

[image]

So due to this issue I can't publish the project? Any tricks on this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just do the following steps,
1. Register zkemkeeper.dll in server (where your side is hosted)
2. Also register above dll on the computer where you are developing it.
Note: best way to register dll of zkemkeeper
download sdk of 32/64 bit from http://www.zkteco.eu/index.php/downloads/software-downloads
run Auto-install_sdk file as a administrator or system.
it will automatically register required dll into your system
Thanks

Comment: if u need any help about it, send email to qpclient@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Just sharing, I've already fixed the issue by using the DLL generated in my bin folder (Interop.zkemkeeper.dll). Now my only problem is this one.

[image]

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by updating my visual studio 2017 into RC2.